# Printrbot Metal Plus with new Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I am still using the originally-suggested version of Cura (for Ubuntu) for my Printrbot Metal Plus (NOT to be confused with the Simple Metal).

My printer was one of the ones with two print heads, and I'd like to make sure that configuring the new Cura software (mine is getting a bit odd due to age and possible slight incompatibility with the OS after all this time) goes correctly.

However, the new versions of Cura no longer list this printer, only having the Simple Metal in the list of preconfigured options.
How much might the manual "add printer" option break my configuration, and will anything cause actual damage to the printer (head/bed collisions, wrong axis measurements, etc)?

Or is there a way to copy the preset options from the old version to the new one? (NOT the .ini file that has MY saved configs, but the default file(s) that the setup wizard uses when opening the program and choosing a printer.)

All the alt-text is showing as white, and I can't connect via USB anymore. I can't *quite* confirm that it's due to it being old, but it's probably a good idea to update it by now, I assume.

[EDIT: My computer died, and took with it that old edition of cura. I have a replacement now, but I can't get that version anymore (to run or to get the settings out of). Does anyone have a list of settings or a config for say, PrusaSlicer or modern cura?]

Comment: Have you tried installing the new version and add a custom 3D printer? It is not very hard to set up. You need a few parameters like printer volume sizes, filament diameter and firmware flavor. It shouldn't be that difficult. Why not install a new version  next to the old and update the question when you run into setup problems? Note that limits and printer configuration are in the firmware.

Comment: atp that, cura allows to export printer settings. from which version do you want to switch zto which?

Comment: I've never had to migrate before, and I also didn't know how that data got stored. I did somehow cause the print head to crash into the print bed hard enough to render it permanently dented in one corner once, so I was a bit leery to take my chances.

Still, is there no way to add "default" printers to modern Cura?

Comment: You can add any printer to Cura or any other tool you want to use. It just need same basic settings as bed volume, firmware flavor, amount of extruders and bed center options. It isn't that difficult to add yourself.

Comment: I don't need to worry about microstepping or Z-increases per layer, etc? How much is it safe to leave default? I also know that it used custom start/end gcode...